# Is it possible to use the 受身形 on a 自動詞

Tags: passive-voice

Hello I was wondering if I could use a 自動詞 with the 受身形 for example:

> ここから、月が見える : from here, the moon is visible (I can see the moon)
>
> ここから、月が見えられる : from here, the moon is visible

I don't understand much the difference between except that in the second one, I feel like it is supposed that there is someone looking at the sky, and the moon is visible by him I think...

I know it could also mean "the moon can be visible" but my question is about the passive voice

Another example:

> 猿が落ちる
>
> 猿が落ちられる

The second sentence doesn't make much sense to me, I would like to know if I'm wrong and how you understand these sentences, thanks!

Comment: In English at least, you cannot use the passive voice with intransitive verbs.  I suspect Japanese intransitives are the same, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you make these example sentences up, or did you find them somewhere?

Comment: Are you aware of the 迷惑受け身 (such as 親に死なれる, *shinu* is intransitive); and do you want to exclude this particular usage from this question?

Comment: 見えられる and 落ちられる are not a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible to use the passive with an intransitive verb in Japanese. It just has a different meaning than what you normally think of when you use passive.

Japanese actually has two types of passives. The first is the one you already know- an action is done to the subject by the agent. The subject is marked with は/が and the agent is marked with に. This can only be used with transitive verbs.

> 彼は車に押し倒された。 He was knocked over by a car.

The second one is often called a "suffering passive". It means something happened, and inflicted misfortune onto someone else. Unlike the first passive, this one doesn't have a direct English equivalent. The subject is the one who "suffers" and is marked with は/が, the agent is marked with に, and the direct object (if the verb is transitive) is marked with を.

> 私は蛇に脚をかまれた。A snake bit me in the leg. (Transitive)
>
> 私は妻に死なれた。My wife died. (Intransitive)

(Native speakers would probably omit the 私は, but I added it for completeness.)

In these examples, the subject/topic is suffering from the action. You should also note that the it is almost always animate. To have an inanimate object suffer wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I was confused about how to use the suffering passive