# The difference between transitive verbs 窮める, 極める, 究める and intransitive verbs 極まる, 窮まるand 谷まる?

Tags: word-choice, homophonic-kanji, kanji-choice

I'm sorry if this question has been answered before, but I did not find a suitable answer. Please provide reliable link if that is the case.

I would like to know the differences between the transitive verbs :

- **極める{きわめる}**
- **究める{きわめる}**
- **窮める{きわめる}**

And also, for the intransitive verbs *related* :

- **極まる{きわまる}**
- **窮まる{きわまる}**
- **谷まる{きわまる}**

Could you provide some simple sentences to understand the meaning of each better ?

Comment: 極める is most used. 究める is used sometimes. 窮める is less used. 谷める is so difficult and most Japanese can’t read this.

Answer (score 2):

According to [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58702/meaning/m0u/) says, **きわま・る〔きはまる〕【極まる／窮まる】の意味**

1. 極{きわ}める/極{きわ}まる : （極める）これより先はないというところまで行き着く。

   - 富士山{ふじさん}の頂上{ちょうじょう}を極{きわ}める。

> **Achieving to the top** of Mt.Fuji.

It is used in **the supremum**/**infimum**, **the ultimate** state.

2.（極める・窮める）極点に達した状態になる。この上もない程度までそうなる。

I think 窮める is used most often in negative sentence like this.

According to this site, [極める・究める・窮めるの違いや使い分けとは？ - 国語力アップ](https://kokugoryokuup.com/kiwameru-tigai/), they say *窮めるとは**物事／状況が行き詰まる事***.

- 困難{こんなん}を窮{きわ}める。
- 進退{しんたい}窮{きわ}まる

> **Getting stuck in the most hardest time/state**

On the other hand, in some settings, it is used in affirmative way like No.4.

And, 極める is used in affirmative sentence.

- 贅沢{ぜいたく}を極{きわ}める。

> Spending **the most luxurious moment**.

3. 残{のこ}るところなく尽{つ}くす。

   - 口{くち}を極{きわ}めてほめる

> Praise with **the great acclaim**.

4.（究める・窮める）深く研究して、すっかり明らかにする。

- 真理{しんり}を究{きわ}める・窮{きわ}める

> Studying truth of things to the full.

5. 終わらせる。
6. 決める。定める。

I think I have not used these meaning other than martial arts.

- 関節技{かんせつわざ}を極{き}める。

> Holding his joints to **get submission**.

According to this site[「谷」はなぜ「たに」と「きわまる」の意味があるのか？ : 常用漢字論―白川漢字学説の検証](http://gaus.livedoor.biz/archives/11286021.html), 
**谷{きわ}まる** is used in the same way as No.2.

- *原文：人亦有言　進退維谷*
- *訓読：人亦（また）言有り　進退維（こ）れ谷（きわま）る*
- *翻訳：昔の人の言葉あり　「進退ともに窮まる」と――『詩経』大雅・桑柔*

*窮まって動きが取れない意味で使われている。**「穴・くぼみ」というコアイメージ**があるから、**くぼみにはまって動きが取れなくなるというイメージに転じた**のである。進むも退くもできなくなることを「**進退谷{しんたいきわま}る**」という。*

It explains they have an image of a hole, which changed into the getting stuck and would not move.

Comment: I think this answer, while very good, could be amazing if you described the difference between transitive and intransitive verbs.  Since some of the words he listed are actually transitive/intransitive pairs, I think that it would be very helpful for the asker to learn beyond the scope of the question you have already effectively answered.

Comment: @ajsmart Thanks for reviewing and suggestion! I hope to, but I am not used to distinguish binary distinction of transitivity carefully. So, I wish some else help to answer that part somewhat...but, maybe why not.

Comment: d, d, downvoted...Where should I fix at first?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/why-is-%e9%81%8a%e3%81%b6-intransitive/52500#52500  Not the greatest explanation, but  I think it's a good starting point.