# その小説には、夫に先に死なれた妻の悲しみが丁寧に書かれていた。

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses, passive-voice

その小説には、夫に先に死なれた妻の悲しみが丁寧に書かれていた。

I was always taught that in a passive sentence like the one written above, the DOER in the action is marked by に, So in the case above the doer is the husband, correct? 夫に  and what passive action he did is 死なれた

So my interpretation of this sentence is:
In this book, the husband killed and murdered his wife, it was a sad tragic affair that was written in the book.
amirite?

Comment: Possible duplicate (regarding suffering passive 「夫に死なれる」): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50432/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23865/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831

Comment: Are you aware 「夫に先に死なれた」 is a relative clause that modifies 「妻」?

Comment: @Chocolate  Hello, yes I am aware that 「夫に先に死なれた」 is a clause ( verb right? ) that modifies a noun 「妻」  So when you have a verb followed by a noun, then the verb acts on the noun.  The Husband FIRSTLY kiils his wife, verb is dead, noun = wife

Comment: えっ  「husband kills his wife」って？？ 　「夫が妻を殺した」ってことですか？  もしかして、「妻が死んだ」と思ってます？ 「夫に死なれた妻」は、「夫に殺された妻」という意味じゃないですよ。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wife's husband died.  This is the suffering passive.

It's saying, (a bit too literally?)

> The wife's *sadness* at the loss of her husband was respectfully written about in the novel.

Put in a looser translation,

> The wife's grief at the loss of her husband was *beautifully* described in the novel.

丁寧 doesn't technically mean *beautiful* but I think this word in English in this context captures nicely the feeling expressed in Japanese.

### Grammar-wise, consider the following

> 妻は夫に先に死なれた

could be rendered

> The wife had her husband die on her.

which kind of captures the *suffering* aspect of the passive.

In the passive construct, に can mark the original subject of the sentence.

So with just this fragment, we could perhaps rephrase this (avoiding the passive) by saying

> 夫が妻の先に死んだ。

> The husband preceded his wife in death. (a rather loose translation again)

But since it's the wife's *grieving/sadness* that is being described, such a non-passive structure would be difficult to work with.

### Breaking this sentence down and rebuilding it bit by bit.

The core sentence is

> その小説には悲しみが書かれていた

> The grief was written about in the novel.

You could ask, "whose grief?"  妻の悲しみ.  *The wife's grief*.

> その小説には妻の悲しみが書かれていた

> The wife's grief was written about in the novel.

You could further ask, "how was it described?" 丁寧に.  *Respectfully*.

> その小説には妻の悲しみが丁寧に書かれていた

Finally, what was the wife grieving?  The fact that her husband died.

> その小説には夫に先に死なれた妻の悲しみが丁寧に書かれていた

Comment: Your answer is complete. Let me just point out that 夫が先に死んだ妻の悲しみ in a non-passive structure is not bad, either.